# HSTMT, UCHAR, SDWORD meaning in ODBC Log

Tags: sql, postgresql, odbc, psqlodbc

I have the following lines in my ODBC Log :

(Scenario: pgAdmin4, using PostgreSQL server through ODBC32 in another application named System Administration)

```
System Admi 6a0-6f8 ENTER SQLExecDirect 
        HSTMT               0x00630718
        UCHAR *             0x036B29C0 [      63] "create table new (npages integer, ifnds integer, ifnid integer)"
        SDWORD                    63
```

I need to know the meaning of `HSTMT`, `UCHAR*` and `SDWORD`. What do those numbers next to them mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article [Everything You Want To Know About ODBC Tracing](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/3049)

> In the trace log, you’ll see the data type of the handle being
>   **SQLHANDLE**, **HENV** / **SQLHENV**, HDBC / **SQLHDBC**, **HSTMT** / **SQLHSTMT**.  This
>   value is unique to the particular series of items being called.  You
>   can search in the trace log for this handle number and each call made
>   on the handle will be shown.  This allows you to pick out only the
>   calls in the trace log that are relevant to your error message. Keep
>   in mind, some applications may create multiple handles. For example,
>   your application may execute three statements consecutively with each
>   residing on a different statement handle.

For examples and more details follow the next nice document:-

[How to read an ODBC trace file.rtf](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/servlet/fileField?id=0BEa0000000PFpc)

Comment: Got it... All that I asked is in a table in **Page 4** of the RTF Document. Thanks @ahmed-abdelqader bro

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj Glad to help you, bro.

Answer (score 1):

This is a record of ODBC tracing

There was a procedure "SQLExecDirect" with statement handle 0x00630718, text parameter (passed as pointer) is "create table ..." and last parameter is size of text (passed as word type). See related [reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f57c9fd8-3464-4a26-b2dd-05897585ca60/how-to-read-the-odbc-trace?forum=sqldataaccess) in MSDOC. 
`HSTMT`,`UCHAR`, `SDWORDS` are data types used by C, C++ MS Windows API.

Comment: The answer by @ahmed-abdelqader bro is far more clear bro. Anyway thanks :)